# Problemas con el nombre del paquete, en Composer

Tags: composer

Estaba tratando de iniciar un archivo composer.json en una carpeta.

Primero pongo `"composer init"`,  despues doy enter y vuelvo a dar enter y me manda el siguiente error;

```
Package name (<vendor>/<name>) [luz maldonado/usando-composer]:
The package name luz maldonado/usando-composer is invalid, it should be 
lowercase and have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name, 
matching: [a-z0-9_.-]+/[a-z0-9_.-]+
```

Si alguien me pudiera explicar un poco y recomendarme lecturas sobre el problema.

De primera impresion el nombre en en vendor esta mal por el espacio, pero donde lo cambio.

Comment: Gracias por la correción

Comment: en el composer.json no?

Comment: No puede haber espacio en el vendor name. Tendría que ser `luz-maldonado/usando-composer`

Comment: @aloMalbarez, no aun no se crea el composer.json en la carpeta donde ejecuto el comando 'composer init',  solo segui este tutorial, ando un poco perdido con el tema solo segui este tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=xpNr_BS1bPw

Comment: @amenadiel, Bien pero entonces donde actualizo el nombre, ese es el problema :)

Comment: Gracias a ambos por contestar, estoy al pendiente. No se que onda, solo queria crear el composer.json en una carpeta para realizar un autoload con composer.

Comment: Estoy al pendiente, para quien me pueda explicar un poco, sobre el problema, recomendarme lecturas o asi.

Comment: lo podes editar, sin apretar enter, te pone por default tu nombre de usuario (del sistema) / el nombre de la carpeta

Comment: es una convención: si te muestra algo entre corchetes [algoasi] es lo que va a tomar si apretas enter sin escribir nada

Comment: Bueno, no entiendo!, muy bien. lo que alcanzo a entender es que antes de apretar enter, le indique   'luz-maldonado/usando-composer' , o sea el nombre corregido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponiendo que ejecutaste `composer init` y el wizard te dijo:

```
Welcome to the Composer config generator  

This command will guide you through creating your composer.json config.

Package name (<vendor>/<name>) [luz maldonado/usando-composer]:
```

Tú escribes:

```
luz-maldonado/usando-composer
```

O si quieres:

```
ejemplo/proyecto
```

Y enter. Luego sigues el wizard. El nombre que te propone tiene un espacio, por eso no te deja seguir. Tienes que ingresar tú uno que sea válido de la forma `<vendor>/<package>` donde vendor y package pueden contener: sólo letras, números, guiones, underscores y puntos.

Comment: Bien funciono, Gracias  :)